# Strange Error amplifier of LDO

Tags: operational-amplifier, ldo, stability, pspice

[image]

I am trying to work out what function the components in inverter colors serve, this is a schematic I have derived from a net-list to make it easier to explain my answer

`E1` is an Error amplifier inside a LDO Regulator (VCVS)

Net `3` is connected to source of a P-Channel MOSFET with upper and lower clips.  (I think this is unusual as I have found that the output of error amplifier is with respect to the input)

Net `9` is the `FB` (Feedback) node,

Net `12`is the reference voltage node,

2.8V output voltage is set using feedback resistive divider. Has dropout voltage of 220mV for 150mA. Nominal input is 3-5.5v.

Is there a name or key word for this type of compensation?

How does this help for stability, PSRR (both) e.g. If I wanted to perform open and closed loop analysis for placement of poles and zeros ? What would this change?

Comment: Presumably you drew the "unknown" circuit so, why did you draw it that way?

Comment: Its netlist derived schematic. And PSRR, load, line, regulation , transients matches currently it matches with datasheet.

Comment: I would recommend you redraw that schematic a little, e.g. in normal op amp symbols, I have a suspicion that E2 is a "buffer", but I am unfamiliar with this style, For E1, it seems flipping it and drawing a line on net 3 between E1/E2 would clear things up, for node 12, you might draw a voltage source, equally if there is a P-mosfet include it,

Comment: As to my thoughts towards the answer, it looks to be some kind of AC gain / attenuation, but without a clearer schematic, I am a bit lost

Comment: @Reroute have edited for better understanding, E2 is upper clip.

Comment: "E2 is upper clip" - that's not common terminology, what does it mean?

Comment: @Finbarr as output of E1 gets high diode D2 gets forward biased and input voltage get clamped. I am unsure about common terminology

Comment: I can't even tell what is an input and what's an output on your schematic, never mind how it works the way you claim it does. It's very hard to tell you how to analyse such a vaguely defined circuit.

Comment: @Finbarr 2.8V output voltage is set using feedback resistive divider. Has dropout voltage of 220mV for 150mA. Nominal input is 3-5.5v. Any other specs required please let me know

Comment: This information should be in the question along with a clear schematic that people can understand.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108702/discussion-between-pai-and-finbarr).

Answer (score 0):

Those are frequency-compensation networks, so the LDO does not oscillate.

I've also seen such networks (implemented with long_channel FETs, etc) on the feedback path from the voltage divider.

===================================

Notice the 10K ohm on the error_amp output. Those 3 RCs turn on, and STAY ON, as the frequency increases.

Fundamentally you have a variable_ratio voltage divider, using 3 shunting networks.

And don't forget the 10Kohm also has to charge and discharge the gate capacitance of the series_regulation FET.

how to analyze it ? basically, you want a **CLOSED LOOP** with little or no ringing. Hence you could run a closed_loop response 1Hertz to 10,000,000 Hz, with 10 steps per decade, and look for peaking (indicating ringing).

And you could perform a **TRANSIENT** load_step of 50%, or a Vin step of 1 volt, and check for little or no ringing even at parameter extremes.

But you should also run an open_loop response, so you get to correlate **ALL**
these various methods and learn some of the theory and the practicality.

One way to run the open_loop was what I showed a switch_reg designer many decades ago. He ended up with the world record for the most personally_designed "boxes" in orbit around the earth {best wishes, Pat}.
His employer threw up hundreds of scientific satellites over the last 40 years, and I'd like to think his use of this trick helped keep him happily employed til he retired.

The trick --- see that feedback voltage divider? place a very large capacitor on the output. Now use a much smaller capacitor to inject some swept_sin at your choice of node.

Comment: How should I theoretically analyse it? Open loop analysis? Or can I understand which type of compensation from any datasheet plots?